# Is it possible to assert a combination of elements

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, assert

I have a field that is automatically filled with the contents of three other fields but with a minus in between the fields. For an example:

> Full Name: John - Joe - Smith (this is automatically filled based on the fields below)
>
> First name: John
>
> Middle name: Joe
>
> Last name: Smith

Now I can put the text of the 3 fields in a string using:

```
String a=river.findElement(by.id("ID-First name"));
String b=river.findElement(by.id("ID-Middle name"));
String a=river.findElement(by.id("ID-Last name"));
```

and I would like to assert the first field with a code somewhat like:

```
assertEquals('a - b - c', driver.findElement(By.id("ID-Full name")).getText());
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

I'm using Eclipse, Selenium webdriver and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
String abc = a + " - " + b + " - " + c;
assertEquals(abc, driver.findElement(By.id("ID-Full name")).getText());
```